# Read "fractions" from .txt file and add them using C

Tags: c, file, math, fractions

I'm trying to read "fractions" from a .txt file and store them in an array to later perform the sum and then simplify the result.

Fractions in the text file are represented as follows(separated by a blankspace):

> 3/2 -7/4 1/6 9/5.

I'm having trouble storing the data into the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20 //just for testing

typedef struct{
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}TFraction;

int main(){
    TFraction F[N];
    fillArray(F);
}
int fillArray(TFraction A[]){
    FILE *txt;
    char skip; //going to be rewritten with "/", can be ignored
    int i=0;

    fp=fopen("fractions.txt","r");

    while(!feof(fp)){
        fscanf(fp,"%d %c %d", A[i].numerator, skip, A[i].denominator);
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Once they array is filled, I should be able to perform the sum.

Any tips or ideas on my proposed solution, I'm open to suggestions on how to solve this.

Comment: You have not stated what trouble you are having and have not asked a question. Stack Overflow is for asking specific questions. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. If the problem is a compiler error message, show the exact text of the compiler error message. If the problem is the program does not execute as you desire, show an exact copy of input that reproduces the problem, an exact copy of the observed output, and a sample of the output desired instead.

Answer (score -1):

As soon as you start parsing text from an external source (from the user, from a file, ... - anything that isn't a string literal in your own code) you can't assume the text is correct and should have adequate error handling that detects problems and describes what the problem is.

For an example, imagine what happens if the file contains "`3.2 -7/4 1/69/5`" - do you want to mistakenly assume that 3.2 is 3/2 and give the wrong answer? Do you you want to assume `1/69/5` is `1/69` followed by `5/???` without telling the user that there's a syntax error on the last fraction?

Once you've solved the parsing problem you'll have another problem...

The addition of fractions involves making sure that the denominators are equal. This is typically done using multiplication - e.g. `3/2 + -7/4 = (3*4)/(2*4) + (-7*2)/(4*2) = 12/8 + -14/8 = (12 + -14)/8 = (-2)/8`.

For many additions; those multiplications cause the numerators and denominators to get very big, possibly too big to fit in an `int`. You can minimize the risk by doing a "fast simplify" (if numerator and divisor are both even then divide them both by 2) or a much more expensive "full simplify" (determine the Greatest Common Divisor and divide numerator and divisor by the GCD) after each addition.

Note that your question says "..and then simplify the result", so you might need code to do "full simplify" anyway.

Alternatively, maybe an estimate with precision loss problems is "close enough" and you can just convert fractions into floating point values before doing addition. This would change the whole nature of the problem.

Finally; if you only need to add the fractions then you don't need to store them and don't need an array to store them. You can have a loop that does "get next fraction; add it to the current total".